# Need to get text between contained within a class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to capture the textfrom each of the  until the end of the matching .. This heading will change many times within the html. I can capture all the data, but is there are better way to do this?

```
<div class="box">
    <a class="visual" href="https://www.example.com">
        <img src="https://www.example.com/img.jpg" alt="image description">
        <h2>Ventura</h2>
    </a>
    <div class="status-row">
        <div class="service">
            <span class="icon nowork"></span> No work                                   
        </div>
        <div class="work">
            <div class="number">0</div> Planned Work
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="box">
    <a class="visual" href="https://www.example.com">
        <img src="https://www.example.com/img.jpg" alt="image description">
        <h2>Boston</h2>
    </a>
    <div class="status-row">
        <div class="service">
            <span class="icon disruption"></span> Disruptions                                   
        </div>
        <div class="no-work">
            <div class="number">0</div> No Work
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    page = requests.get(url,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

s = 'Ventura'

for x in soup.findAll("div",  {"class": ["box", "status-row"]}):
    z = x.get_text()
    if  s in z.strip():
        print(z)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Exactly what data do you want to extract from this example?

Comment: Heading --there will be a different heading for each item
 No work -- this could change based on weather conditions
 Planned Work -- this could change based on weather conditions

Comment: _capture the text from each of the until the end of the matching_  - what does that mean?

Comment: Can you post few more div and also mentioned your expected output want to get in your post which help to identify OP to know what you are looking after

Comment: Your question is unclear. Try to reformat the question and specify what you want to do exactly, what is the input and what is the corresponding desired output.